# How to show "Please wait" in self-hosted shiny app until packages are attached

Tags: r, shiny

In the applications hosted in the shinyapps.io we find a "please wait" message until the libraries are attached or server is ready. Do someone know how we can achieve the same with a self-hosted shiny apps?

Thank you.

-

Comment: Hey, not sure that this is exactly what you want, but please take a look: https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/loading-screen

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. I am aware of it, but it is not what I am looking for. I need to show loading message before all packages are loaded. So I don't think is possible to do with any package. I guess, shinyapps.io does that with a iframe.

Comment: Maybe something along these lines:     https://samhinshaw.com/blog/lazy-loading-r-packages-in-shiny/  Not a package, as you said, but serves as reference.

Comment: @José Luiz Ferreira thank you. This is a good approach, but it requires you to press a button for initiating the shiny app. I think the link you showed is the best solution so far.

Comment: not sure if you are still on this, but I recently came across the library `waiter` and it has a function `waiter_show_on_load()` that I am pretty sure you can use for your problem (for me it loads imediatelly). Take a look in the docs: https://github.com/JohnCoene/waiter